# R - extracting beta and alpha from regression within a window

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series, tidyverse, linear-regression

I have this dataframe:

```
structure(list(X_ = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), Y_ = c(0.00485082338451504, 
-0.0168046606213001, 0.0271922543834244, 0.00553894528785559, 
0.0459064669618974, 0.0735144938632293, 0.0368605806880207, 0.0597490764776278, 
0.0244300474780141, 0.00904348896641594), Window_5 = c(-4, -3, 
-2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), Window_2 = c(-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
6, 7, 8)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), na.action = structure(c(`1` = 1L), class = "exclude"))
```

```r
  X_     Y_      Window_5 Window_2
  <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1     1  0.00485       -4       -1
2     2 -0.0168        -3        0
3     3  0.0272        -2        1
4     4  0.00554       -1        2
5     5  0.0459         0        3
6     6  0.0735         1        4
7     7  0.0369         2        5
9     9  0.0244         4        7
10    10  0.00904        5        8
```

Where `Window_5 = X_-5` and `Window_2 = X_-2`. I'm looking for the beta and alpha of a simple regression line, where alpha and beta:

[image]

However, the challenge is I need those parameters for each row given a window for `X_`. For example, for `X_=7` the regression line should consider only rows where `X_` starts at `Window_5` and ends at `Window_2`, which in this case where `X_=7` the window will be from `X_=2` to `X_=5`.

So, the expected output would be: (I did this in excel and double-checked it, so the values should be right)

[image]

PS: If you can add the error, that's would be great but is not needed strictly speaking.

Comment: I provided data as an image to have a better view. You don't need type in as I gave you the reproducible example of the image (the first bunch of code). And it's X_-2 , I will correct it!

Comment: Can you please re-edit your question so that all of the textual information is shown as text and not as images?  Text is more accessible in several ways (via screen readers for the visually impaired, searchable ...)

Comment: Yes! I'm trying to do the edit you just did (I had to delete it because the values of "Window_2" were the wrong ones)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have code that looks like it should do what you want.  It's not "tidy" though ... (it should use `purrr::pmap` + `broom::tidy` + ...)

```r
wfun <- function(i, data) {
  start <- data$Window_5[i]
  end <- data$Window_2[i]
  if (start<=0) return(data.frame(Alpha=NA,Alpha_SE=NA,
                                  Beta=NA, Beta_SE=NA))
  cc <- coef(summary(lm(Y_ ~ X_, data=data[start:end,])))
  data.frame(Alpha=cc["(Intercept)","Estimate"],
             Alpha_SE=cc["(Intercept)","Std. Error"],
             Beta=cc["X_","Estimate"],
             Beta_SE=cc["(Intercept)","Std. Error"])

}

res <- lapply(seq(nrow(dd)),wfun, data=dd)
do.call(rbind,res)
```

Comment: I corrected the data now! Your solution gives me this error: ´Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'dd' not found´ when I replace "dd" in t(sapply(....)) for my dataframe name "df"

Comment: Still giving an error when I replace dd for df in: res <- lapply(seq(nrow(df)),wfun, data=df). The error is: Error in start:end : Argumento NA/NaN. By the way, I solved the data errors :). How were you able to put the table in colors? I replaced the image by code-text but doesn't show it in colors.

Comment: Same error: "Error in start:end : Argumento NA/NaN" where I run the res <- lapply(....) line

Comment: I runs now, but (1) it doesn't return X_, Y_ and the Windows columns and (2) could you explain it a little bit what it does? I understand everything until the code line: "Alpha=cc((Intercept))... What is cc? It's similar to the vector "c()"? and could you explain the last two lines? Specially the lapply logic (You can use %>% if you think will be clearer)

Comment: (1) you can `cbind()` the results to your original data frame; (2) `cc` is defined in the line above the one you're asking about. (3) `lapply()` runs `wfun()` for each value of `i` and returns the results as a list

Comment: But cbind() will just concatenate it and I can't know if the Alpha or Beta returned are in different order than the original dataframe. I can check 1 by 1 in this example, but I can't check 1 by 1 in my 80k rows xD. Could you please clarify your explanation? :)

Comment: I agree you should use `data.frame()` instead of `cbind`, but ... we *just* computed the values in the row order from the original data frame, so they are going to match unless something **really** weird is happening ...

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is a sliding window regression of fixed width (4 in your case, but not exactly as your example is formatted), maybe look at the rollRegres package?

```
library(rollRegres)
roll_regres(Y_ ~ X_, data = dd, width=4)
```